# Why are my add_foreign_key on_delete: :cascade designations not being transferred to the schema

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-migrations, postgresql-9.6

In an effort to properly handle Postgres's ForeignKeyViolation warnings, I've gone through each of my models and added on_delete: commands as shown below.

The format I'm following is

`add_foreign_key <:named_table>, <:related_table>, on_delete: :cascade`

However, after making these changes and running `rails db:reset` I notice these extra parameters are not being passed into the resulting schema.rb file and I still receive the abovementioned error when trying to delete an image.

Is there something I'm doing wrong either in my procedure or my syntax? Thank you in advance!

**12345_create_document_images.rb**

```
class CreateDocumentImages < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :document_images do |t|
      t.references :document, foreign_key: true
      t.references :image, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end

    add_foreign_key :document_images, :documents, on_delete: :cascade
    add_foreign_key :document_images, :images, on_delete: :cascade
  end
end
```

**schema.rb**

```
 add_foreign_key "document_images", "images"
 add_foreign_key "document_images", "documents"
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you say this:

```
t.references :document, foreign_key: true
```

The `foreign_key: true` option creates the same foreign key that:

```
add_foreign_key :document_images, :documents, on_delete: :cascade
```

does. When the `add_foreign_key` method executes, the FK already exists so it should trigger an `PG::DuplicateObject` exception at least it does for me. I'm not sure why you're not getting an exception but that doesn't matter, what does matter is that the FK from `create_table` will be there before you try to add an FK with `on_delete: :cascade` via your `add_foreign_key` calls.

The solution is to let `t.references` create the FK with `on_delete: :cascade` and leave out the explicit `add_foreign_key` calls:

```
class CreateDocumentImages < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :document_images do |t|
      t.references :document, foreign_key: { on_delete: :cascade }
      t.references :image, foreign_key: { on_delete: :cascade}
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

I also renamed the migration to match what it is really doing.

Added by Spectator6: Something else that @mu_is_too_short introduced me to is the use of `rails db:migrate:redo` which led me to also learn about `rails db:migrate:reset`. Previously, I had only been using `rails db:reset`, but the moment I implemented his suggestions and then ran `rails db:migration:reset` followed by `rails db:reset`, everything clicked! The schema reflected the new database triggers on the foreign_key and trying out the functionality in development worked as expected. Very cool! All props to @mu_is_too_short!

Comment: @mu_is_too_short Thank you for the detailed explanation! Unfortunately, the problem persists... I still get the same PG::ForeignKeyViolation error...

Comment: @mu_is_too_short The fact you said you get an exception from PG when double defining the foreign_key method and I don't makes me think that has something do with why the schema is not being generated properly

Comment: Have you fixed the migration and done a `db:migrate:redo` on it?

Comment: I'll give that a shot and report back! I was previously using `rails db:reset`

Comment: Still no luck with `rails db:migrate:redo`  Here's something I noticed too. The schema file appears to be updating per the file explorer modified timestamp, however within the schema file itself it says ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20180321190239) As a check, I went ahead and commented out several migration files before running the `db:migrate:redo` command and yet those tables still show in the schema. How weird...

Comment: @mu_is_too_short IT WORKED!! Thank you thank you thank you for your help with this, you rock!!!